# h:commandButton click throwing IllegalArgumentException

Tags: jsf, primefaces, illegalargumentexception

Thanks in advance for any pointers/ideas.

I'm using JSF 2.1, Primefaces 3.2 and Jboss7.0 Final.  My problem is that the following .XHTML is throwing:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: mainForm:testTabs_Tabs-tabs:j_idt34
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:137)
com.maketechnologies.framework.web.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:34)
root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: mainForm:testTabs_Tabs-tabs:j_idt34
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.validateId(UIComponentBase.java:548)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.setId(UIComponentBase.java:363)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.doExistingComponentActions(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:428)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:155)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.composite.ImplementationHandler.apply(ImplementationHandler.java:81)
javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:152)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.CompositeComponentTagHandler.applyCompositeComponent(CompositeComponentTagHandler.java:348)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.CompositeComponentTagHandler.applyNextHandler(CompositeComponentTagHandler.java:190)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:103)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:178)
com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:395)
com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:366)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:108)
javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:164)
javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:308)
com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:367)
com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:346)
com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:155)
com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:152)
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:744)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf2.impl.listener.phase.CodiLifecycleWrapper.render(CodiLifecycleWrapper.java:126)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:137)
com.maketechnologies.framework.web.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:34)
```

Here is my XHTML code (i couldn't post all of it, it's causing formatting issues):

```html
<p:outputPanel id="testTabs_Tabs" layout="block" styleClass="tabLayout">
    <p:tabView dynamic="true" id="testTabs_Tabs-tabs" onTabChange="if (isDirtyAction()) {return false;}">
        <p:tab id="testTabs_Tabs-Tab1" label="#{testTabsMsg.testTabs_Tabs_Tab1}" title="#{testTabsMsg.testTabs_Tabs_Tab1}">
            <p:outputPanel id="Tabs_Tab1" layout="block" styleClass="formLayout">
                <table class="formLayout">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <p:outputPanel id="Tab1_TestPanel" layout="block" styleClass="formLayout">
                                <table class="formLayout">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">
                                            <p:outputPanel id="TestPanel_UpperPanel" layout="block" styleClass="formLayout">
                                                <table class="formLayout">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="2">
                                                            <p:outputPanel id="UpperPanel_Buttons" layout="block" styleClass="formLayout">
                                                                <p:outputPanel id="UpperPanel_Buttons_buttonGroup" layout="block" styleClass="buttonGroup">
                                                                    <t:commandButton action="#{testTabs.doSomething}" disabled="#{testTabs.doSomethingDisabled}" id="buttons_doSomething" value= "#{testTabsMsg.testTabs_Tabs_Tab1_TestPanel_UpperPanel_Buttons_doSomething}" />
                                                                </p:outputPanel>
                                                            </p:outputPanel>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </p:outputPanel>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">
                                            <p:outputPanel id="TestPanel_ShowMeHideMe">
                                                <p:outputPanel id="TestPanel_ShowMeHideMe_inner" layout="block" rendered="#{testTabs.showMeHideMeRendered}" styleClass="formLayout">
                                                    <table class="formLayout">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th>
                                                                <t:label forId="Hi:Hi" value="#{testTabsMsg.testTabs_Tabs_Tab1_TestPanel_ShowMeHideMe_Hi}"/>
                                                            </th>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <t:inputText id="Hi" label="#{testTabsMsg.testTabs_Tabs_Tab1_TestPanel_ShowMeHideMe_Hi}" value="#{testTabs.testText}"/>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                    <p:outputPanel id="TestPanel_ShowMeHideMe_buttonGroup" layout="block" styleClass="buttonGroup">
                                                        <t:commandButton action="#{testTabs.done}" ajax="true" id="showMeHideMe_done" updateTarget="@form" value="#{testTabsMsg.testTabs_Tabs_Tab1_TestPanel_ShowMeHideMe_done}"/>
                                                    </p:outputPanel>
                                                </p:outputPanel>
                                            </p:outputPanel>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab action="#{testTabs.tab2}" id="testTabs_Tabs-Tab2" label="#{testTabsMsg.testTabs_Tabs_Tab2}" title="#{testTabsMsg.testTabs_Tabs_Tab2}"/>
    </p:tabView>
</p:outputPanel>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</p:outputPanel>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

and here is my backing bean code:

```
package ca.sandbox;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.scope.conversation.ViewAccessScoped;
import org.jboss.seam.international.status.Messages;
import com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.annotation.URLAction;
import com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.annotation.URLMapping;
import com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.annotation.URLMappings;
import ca.sandbox.AbstractBackingBean;

@Named
@ViewAccessScoped
@URLMappings(mappings = {
        @URLMapping(id = "testTabs", pattern = "/sandbox/testTabs/#{iid : testTabs.id}", viewId = "/sandbox/testTabs.jsf"),
        @URLMapping(id = "testTabsNew", pattern = "/sandbox/testTabs", viewId = "/sandbox/testTabs.jsf") })
public class TestTabs extends AbstractBackingBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String hi;
    private Long id;
    private String testText = "this is working!!!";
    private boolean panelShown = false;

    public TestTabs() {
    }

    public String getHi() {
        return hi;
    }

    public void setHi(String hi) {
        this.hi = hi;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @URLAction
    public void load() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("break here");
    }

    public String done() {
        panelShown = false;
        return null;
    }

    public String doSomething() {
        panelShown = true;
        return null;
    }

    public boolean getShowMeHideMeRendered() {
        return panelShown;
    }

    public boolean getDoSomethingDisabled() {
        return panelShown;
    }

    public String getTestText() {
        return testText;
    }

    public void setTestText(String testText) {
        this.testText = testText;
    }

    // @formatter:off
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that one of the arguments for the `mainForm:testTabs_Tabs-tabs` component is wrong. After some researching, I've found that `p:tab` has no action component attribute,

```html
<p:tab action="#{testTabs.tab2}" id="testTabs_Tabs-Tab2" label="#{testTabsMsg.testTabs_Tabs_Tab2}" title="#{testTabsMsg.testTabs_Tabs_Tab2}"/>
```

Try changing the code of tab2 to this

```html
<p:tab id="testTabs_Tabs-Tab2" label="#{testTabsMsg.testTabs_Tabs_Tab2}" title="#{testTabsMsg.testTabs_Tabs_Tab2}"/>
```

Comment: An action is not mandatory on the p:tab - for now, because I haven't implemented the functionality for the second tab, I have left it out....  I suppose I could try it...

Comment: @Nena has this worked? If doesn't, is still giving you the same error?